# Diceroll Probability Method Structure

Tags: java

the problem I'm having is quite basic, however this is something I have not grasped very well.  The program below uses recursion to calculate the probability of a given number of dice (entered by the user) totaling to a number picked by the user.

From what I understand, the method DiceRoll is a part of the class Diceroll.  However when I attempt to call the method, I get an error.  I believe there is something fundamentally wrong with the structure of this program.  Could someone help me out?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DiceRoll {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        double dice = 0;
        int r = 0;
        System.out.println("Please input the number of dice you wish to roll between 0 and 25: ");
        if (in.nextInt() < 0 || in.nextInt() > 25){
            System.out.println("invalid number of dice");
        } else {
            dice = in.nextInt();            
        }
        System.out.println("What number between 0 and 125 do you wish to roll?");
        if (in.nextInt() < 0 || in.nextInt() > 125) {
            System.out.println("invalid number, please choose between 0 and 125");
        } else {
            r = in.nextInt();
        }
    }

    double DiceRoll(double dice,int r) {
        if (dice==1 && (r<1 || r>6)){ 
            return 0;
        }
        if (dice==1 && (r>=1 && r<=6)){
            return (1.0/6);
        } else {
            return ((1.0/6)*DiceRoll(dice-1,r-1));
        }
    }
}

DiceRoll(dice, r)
```

Comment: You could at least *try* to format your question.

Comment: My apologies, Hunter.  I'll try to edit it up.

Comment: @MrD sorry I already edited the question.

Answer (score 2):

All code in Java needs to be contained within a method or class. You can't just have a call to `DiceRoll` floating in the middle of your class.

What you really want to do is get your input from the user like you are currently, then inside the `main` method call `DiceRoll`.

Comment: Could you help me break down the exact structure of this program?  From what I understand, the class DiceRoll contains the main method which contains the scanner and the method, DiceRoll, which is dependent on the variables dice and r.  From Neil's comment, I moved the DiceRoll method into the main method.  You are saying that I can then call the DiceRoll method from within the main method and it should work?

Comment: Never mind, I've figured it out for the most part.  I placed the DiceRoll method outside of the main method (but still within the class) and called the method in the main method.  Thank you!  Now I need to work on the recursion part, but that does't seem to hard.

Answer (score 0):

remove Diceroll method from inside the main method ^_^

EDIT:
realized the DiceRoll method is not declared inside the main method but the call to it is placed outside of the main method, move it inside and it should work

Comment: DiceRoll isn't in their main method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the line

```
DiceRoll(dice, r)
```

In addition, rather than using

```
double DiceRoll(double dice,int r)
```

which would require you to instantiate an object, use

```
static double RollDice(double dice, int r)
```

As a static method, you don't have to instantiate an object of that type in order for it to work. I've also renamed it so that the compiler won't complain about it looking like an invalid constructor method. With a static method, you would simply call

```
RollDice(dice, r)
```

at the end of your `main` method.

There's also another problem with your code - the input isn't going to behave like you are wanting. I assume you want it to check if the input is valid, and then ask again if it is not. Currently, it will say it is not valid then do nothing, but when it is valid it will immediately expect another number. Change your statements to look like this:

```
System.out.println("Please input the number of dice you wish to roll between 0 and 25: ");
dice = in.nextInt();
while (dice < 0 || dice > 25){
    System.out.println("invalid number of dice");
    dice = in.nextInt();            
}
```

This will only get another number if they entered an invalid number, and will loop until they give a valid input.

Comment: Oh, and I'm pretty sure that, as it is, your algorithm for calculating the probability isn't going to give the right answer.